# Windows Task Schedulr not connecting to SQL Server Database through .Net exe

Tags: sql-server, windows, scheduled-tasks

On A Windows 2012 server, I am using Task Scheduler to execute .exe but it is not connecting to SQL Server.

A Network related or instance specific error while connecting to SQL Server instance specified.

Please let me know the web.config details to connect to SQL Server from task scheduler

I checked remote connection and TCP protocol issue everything seems ok

Comment: Where is the database running?  Are you able to connect to it with other programs?  is the .exe you are running something you built, or off-the-shelf software we might be familiar with?  Any detail you can provide will be very helpful!